# Xcode Run script issue when copy the run script from Microsoft Word Document

Tags: xcode, build, ms-word, formatting, run-script

We have created iOS SDK with supporting both Simulator and Device so while While sharing we are also providing instruction to Developer to remove the unwanted architecture by adding the Run script in their project. This run script is included in the SDK word document. When the developer tried to copy the run script from the word document and paste in their Xcode, then it throws an error.

Run script

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name 'xyz.framework'  -or -name 'abc.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH" EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

**Word Doc Screenshot**

[image]

Note: After adding if we quite the Xcode and open it again then its working fine.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the ms-word document in which you have the script? Also, please detail the error which you get.

Comment: @Arul added the details